# Grails Heroku unresolved dependency issues (MySQL), Heroku and BuildConfig.groovy?

Tags: grails, heroku

When I run

```
git push heroku master
```

from my grails app directory Heroku complains

```
UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES:   mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16: not found
```

My BuildConfig.groovy contains the lines:

```
   dependencies { 
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
}
```

as well as:

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```

and I have an updated Maven installed, and Maven shows it has this connector [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.16), and indeed indicates the Gradle form of the dependency is what I have.

Heroku shows one must update the pom.xml for non-standard libraries, but this should not be the case here?

Please advise, do I have to use maven pom.xml for common dependencies such as this?  Does Heroku understand BuildConfig.groovy dependencies at all?   From the [grails heroku plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-heroku/docs/manual/guide/3%20Tutorials.html) examples that would seem to be the case, so not sure why it isn't working here.

Thanks

---------- Per comment, I do have maven referenced in build.gradle (apparently it comes this way), namely:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath "commons-io:commons-io:1.4"
   }
}
```

----------------------- Per comment, Here's the full output of what it tried -----

```
 Environment set to development
 :: problems summary ::
 :::: WARNINGS
      module not found: mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16

  ==== grailsPlugins: tried

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

/tmp/build_242ryu5333xu0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

  ==== grailsHome: tried

/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.xml

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

  ==== grailsHome: tried

/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/dist/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.xml

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/dist/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

  ==== grailsHome: tried

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/.grails/plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

  ==== grailsCentral: tried

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java/tags/RELEASE_5_1_16/grails-mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

  ==== grailsCore: tried

-- artifact mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16!mysql-connector-java.jar:

http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-mysql-connector-java/tags/RELEASE_5_1_16/grails-mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar

      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
      :: mysql#mysql-connector-java;5.1.16: not found
      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Looks right.  Maybe a transient issue.  Can you try again?  One other thing... Make sure you have gradle configured to search maven central.

Comment: Thanks James. Haven't configured gradle.  Can you by chance list a good reference on doing this?  Does this mean to that Heroku plus Grails doesn't need MAVEN / pom.xml, only Gradle?

Comment: Interestingly the above heroku command seems to download everything else -- i.e. Spring and all sorts of Java libraries, Grails 1.3.7, and the grails plugins I'm using.  So it's finding everything except the single dependency I listed :-)

Comment: But looks like build.gradle comes pre-configured with statements:  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "commons-io:commons-io:1.4"
    }
}

Comment: fyi - re-running produces the same error.

Comment: Do you have both pom.xml and build.gradle?

Comment: Also, it looks like it's not actually trying Maven Central, so locally it's pulling it from your local repo.  Then on Heroku it can't find the dep.  You can try to clear out your local repo to repo locally.

Comment: No, I have a build.gradle but no pom.xml per section 3.2 of the Grails Heroku plugin (http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-heroku/docs/manual/guide/3%20Tutorials.html).  I removed the mavenLocal() repository addition in BuildConfig.groovy, but that didn't help.  We'll look to clear local repo now (wherever that is).

Comment: I blew away the .git directory and started fresh, and it got past this error.   Unfortunately the grails heroku plugin appears to be failing now.  Will repost as a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing various things I totally blew away the .git repository directory and started from scratch.  After doing so, I no longer got this dependency error.  As such, the cause is still a mystery, but in case you encounter this error, you may wish to try this (with care).